# Decoupling a Mockito test from a specifc test value?

Tags: java, string, junit, mockito

I am trying to test the method findById() method in the class below that reads data from my Database using the CrudRepository:

**Class under test:**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer>
{

    Person findById(String id);
}
```

Below is my test class, the test is currently passing but I would like to change it so that if the id "1" I am testing with is removed from my database, I can still run my test. I.e. do not rely on data within the database.

How can I do so?

**Test Class:**

```
public class PersonRepositoryTest {

    @Mock
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //Initialize the mocked class and ensure that it is not null
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        assertThat(personRepository, notNullValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindById() throws ParseException {

        //test string
        String id = "1";

        //when it is called, return
        when(personRepository.findById(anyString())).thenReturn(new Person());

        Person person = personRepository.findById(id);
        assertThat(person, notNullValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: What you describe is actually what is achieved using a mock framework: You are not using the real database, but define the answers upfront. Your current mock will always return a new Person instance, no matter what id you are querying.

Comment: Ok so how should I change my current test?

Comment: It is unclear what you would like to achieve, you are already independant from a real database. So what is your goal?

Comment: but within my test is personRepository not calling the database to look for the id "1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the Post comments by @Thomas, you are just mocking the database. I'm assuming you want to write a negative test case when the ID is 1.

You can just return null, instead of person Object. Instead of Matchers, pass a specific value to differentiate your positive and negative test cases.

Positive Case -

```
when(personRepository.findById(2)).thenReturn(new Person());
```

Negative Case -

```
when(personRepository.findById(1)).thenReturn(null);
```

Comment: but within my test is personRepository not calling the database to look for the id "1"?

Comment: No, that is why tou introduced a mock, to be independant of the real database.

Comment: Thats what mock is all about right ? With mock, you are just mocking the behaviour of real interaction with the DB for unit testing.